# Java API for gdb (GNU Debugger)

Tags: java, api, gdb

I would like to control the gdb (GNU Debugger) from a Java Application: start a debugging session, setting breakpoints, stepping etc.
One solution for this problem is of course to run the gdb via:

```
Runtime.exec(String command);
```

The downside of this approach is the additional coding effort for parsing results, sending commands etc. To overcome this, I would like to use an existing API or library (preferably written in Java) which acts as middleware between my Java program and the gdb.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the [Eclipse CDT source](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development#Getting_the_Sources).  It is open source and you could even integrate it into whatever you're building.